# bind integer to fillproperty

Tags: javafx, data-binding

I want to bind an integerProperty to the fillProperty of a shape so the change of the integer will change the color of the shape.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,20);
IntegerProperty intProp = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

rect.fillProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createObjectBinding(
        () -> Color.rgb(intProp.get(), intProp.get(), intProp.get()),intProp));
```

But I get an error :

> A bound value cannot be set

How could I do?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with this code alone. Do you try to set `rect.fill` somewhere? Analyze the stacktrace to identify the statement setting the value and find out, where the binding is created for the property involved. BTW: The binding you create is the other way around: you bind `fill` to a binding created based on the `IntegerProperty` not the other way round.

Comment: tks! I had a rect.setFill(Color.BLACK) somewhere in my code. Removing it solve my problem!